# How to save an image in uv editor even when closing blender?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, customization

I have a palette image in my uv editor to color my models, but every time when I close blender, I have to reopen it again, is there a way to save it in my workplace without reopening it always?

THANKS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setup your image(s) however you would like before modifying anything else in a *new* clean .blend file.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to save the modified start-up file as the new default, and the images (along with any other changes, materials, objects, etc.) will be present going forward.

If you decide to go back to the default configuration, then you can [Load Factory Settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/preferences/introduction.html#load-factory-settings)

Documentation is [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/data_system/files/startup_file.html#startup-file)

Comment: that's logical but I closed blender and I opened it again the cube was purple without the texture, and when I opened the saved .blend file the texture was there

Comment: interesting...works fine on my system, have kept images in my start up file for some time.

Comment: thanks a lot for making it easy, it didn't work but I saved a startup.blend and everytime I open blender I open it, that's better than importing the image

Comment: @18.99 You have to   Image menu > Pack  the image for it to be saved inside the .blend file.. also not a bad idea to click the shield 'Fake User' icon, so it's not considered an orphan, and deleted on save. I have a folder of startup .blends I can return to for switching between tasks.